# How to go to Edit Mode in FormView?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, formview

I have FormView:

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvReport" runat="server" DefaultMode="ReadOnly" AllowPaging="false" OnModeChanging="fvReport_ModeChanging" DataKeyNames="id">

protected void fvReport_ModeChanging(Object sender, FormViewModeEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.NewMode)
        {
            case FormViewMode.Edit:
                fvReport.AllowPaging = false;
                break;
        }
    }
```

in ItemTamplate I put LinkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'>Редактировать</asp:LinkButton>
```

Of course, FormView has EditItemTemplate section.

When I click Button, FormView is refreshed and stays in ReadOnly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you have to call ChangeMode method of FormView and pass the mode

```
fvReport.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);
```

Comment: thanks, in result I did as you) but I thought that FormView goes to edit mode automatically if CommandName set "Edit". [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formviewmodeeventargs%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Another option which I commonly use to go into edit mode from a formView is to add and define the EditItemTemplate element. This makes it a lot easier to make your application editable.

Within your formView you may need to change your `DefaultMode` to Edit. Also in your code behind try:

```
protected void fvReport_ModeChanging(Object sender, FormViewModeEventArgs e)
{

}

protected void lbEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lbEdit = (LinkButton)fvReport.FindControl("lbEdit");

    if (sender == lbEdit)
    {
        fvReport.DataBind();
        fvReport.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be other reasons why your `FormView` isn't switching over.  It's usually down to badly formatted HTML. Your designer sometimes tells you of malformed sections by displaying something like this...

[image]

On those occasions when you don't get this obvious message, `FormView` not switching over is usually down to something a little less obvious, such as bad `AssociatedControlId` attributes.  I would recommend looking at you labels, validators and anything where a control has to be associated to another. Something as small as this...

```html
<asp:Label runat="server"
    ID="labelAccessGrantedBy"
    Text="Access Granted By"
    AssociatedControlID="textAccessGranted" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server"
    ID="textAccessGrantedBy"
    CssClass="wmioSmall wFull"
    Text='<%# Bind("access_granted_by") %>' />
```

Notice the deliberate use of `textAccessGranted` above, rather than the actual `textAccessGrantedBy` `TextBox`? That's where the command handling has failed for me in the past.